# nsis File folder parametric directory

Tags: nsis

I wish made a function to add some files into some folder, 'cause I need to add more files.

here is my code of the function:

```
Function "addElement"
    DetailPrint $0
    CreateDirectory $INSTDIR\data\Element\$0
    SetOutPath $INSTDIR\data\Element\$0

    File /r "${binFolder}\data\Element\$0\*.*"
FunctionEnd
```

and here I call it:

```
strcpy $0 "Element_1"
call "addElement"

strcpy $0 "Element_2"
call "addElement"

strcpy $0 "Element_3"
call "addElement"
```

the nsis gives this error:

at the line `File /r...` gives *-> no files found.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$0` is a variable and variables are used at run-time, the `File` instruction needs to know the filename at compile-time!

Replace the function with a macro:

```
!macro addElement fname
    DetailPrint "${fname}"
    CreateDirectory "$INSTDIR\data\Element\${fname}"
    SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\data\Element\${fname}"

    File /r "${binFolder}\data\Element\${fname}\*.*"
!macroend

...

Section

!insertmacro addElement foo
!insertmacro addElement bar
!insertmacro addElement baz
```